# How to reload the div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div id="memberschatcntnr" style="width: 529px; height: 450px; background-color: white; border-top : 3px solid black; border-bottom: 3px solid black; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 10px;">
    <?php include('memberschat.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Hello, thats the div with the content of a chat that I want to refresh every x seconds, but when I do that with ajax, the styles of the page will not influde in the new requested code, is there a other possibility?

look:

```
<form action="memberschatprocess.php" target="hiddenform" method="post" id="form">
    <input style="display: none;" id="formname" name="formname" value="<?php @$name=$_GET["name"]; echo $name; ?>" />
    <input name="formcoment" onkeypress="validar(event)" type="text" style="width: 519px; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 25px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px gray; height: 40px; border: none; font-size: 120%; outline: none; background-color: #E1E1E1;" />
</form>

<iframe style="display: none;" name="hiddenform"></iframe>
```

thats the form code, that will be request without reload the page

Comment: Can you show your JS code?

Comment: yes of course i will post it

Comment: rre you doing ajax using jquery? if don't please post your js code.

Comment: @PwterGemul and in English?